# Linking JS with web part in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, javascript, html

I created a sharepoint task list with the column "Priority" according to this guide: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-0a786cdd#content

Then I linked the JS, which I saved on m SharePoint under the "Miscellaneous" Part of the Web Part. Now, what the script is supposed to do, is to look for the column "priority" and replace the words "High" with a red png-picture, the words "normal" with a yellow png-picture etc...

However it seems like the JS is not working at all, because the list does not Change it appearence at all. I tried different approaches like, not replacing the words with Pictures and only changing their colours etc, however ist not working so far

Here is the full code:

```
(function () { 

    var priorityFiledContext = {}; 
    priorityFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
    priorityFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        "Priority": { "View": priorityFiledTemplate } 
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(priorityFiledContext); 

})(); 

function priorityFiledTemplate(ctx) { 

    var priority = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; 

    if(priority=="High") { 
        return "<img src='/sites/020014/Name/Biblio/AmpelRed.png'/>";
    }           
    else if(priority=="Normal") { 
        return "<img src='/sites/020014/Name/Biblio/AmpelAmber.png'/>";
    } 
    else if(priority=="Low") { 
        return "<img src='/sites/020014/Name/Biblio/AmpelGreen.png'/>";
    } 

}
```

now I am wondering, maybe this part of the code:

```
var priority = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
```

is supposed to find the "priority" coloumn, but im not sure, how it works...

thanks in advance!

Comment: hello can you share the path how you are refereing in the Miscellaneous property and have tried placing alert in the script.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. May be your JS file is not loading properly.    I would recommend to try the solution provided by @Sunilsahu. That should work...

Answer (score 1):

think its with refering the JS file in JS link property.
A simple /v.js link will not work. Either of the following SharePoint tokens should be used instead:

For js file stored in SiteCollection

**~sitecollection/your file path.**

like :-

```
~sitecollection/SiteAssets/jslink.js
```

And for js file stored in SubSite/Web

**~site/SiteAssets/your file path.**

like :-

```
~site/SiteAssets/jslink.js
```

[For more tokens you may refer](https://www.dynamics101.com/jslink-sharepoint-2013-get-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to link your JS using a content editor webpart.

while in edit mode navigate to Insert -> Media and Content ->Content Eiditor
then edit the Content Editor to pull the URL path of your saved .js file.